# Tensorflow Model not Restoring and Running Properly

Tags: tensorflow

I have built and successfully trained a convolutional model, however I cannot manage to restore the model and run my evaluation on it. The program throws a bunch of errors without giving an answer.

My code for the evaluation is here:

```
import tensorflow as tf

import main
import Process
import Input

eval_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/model.ckpt-98"
checkpoint_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/checkpoint"


def evaluate():
  with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
    images, labels = Process.eval_inputs()
    forward_propgation_results = Process.forward_propagation(images)
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    top_k_op = tf.nn.in_top_k(forward_propgation_results, labels, 1)

  with tf.Session(graph = g) as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
    saver.restore(sess, eval_dir)
    for i in range(100):
        print(sess.run(top_k_op))

def main(argv = None):
    evaluate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

My output to the eval looks looks like this: but without the program running. It just stays stuck there.

```
 E tensorflow/core/client/tensor_c_api.cc:485] /Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/Prostate_Cancer_Data1.bin
     [[Node: ReaderRead = ReaderRead[_class=["loc:@FixedLengthRecordReader", "loc:@input_producer"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](FixedLengthRecordReader, input_producer)]]
ERROR:tensorflow:Exception in QueueRunner: /Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/Prostate_Cancer_Data1.bin
 [[Node: ReaderRead = ReaderRead[_class=["loc:@FixedLengthRecordReader", "loc:@input_producer"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](FixedLengthRecordReader, input_producer)]]
```

The following is the main part of my program where I save the model and the checkpoint files.

```
import Input
import Process

import time
import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
from datetime import datetime

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

def train():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        images, labels = Process.inputs()

        forward_propgation_results = Process.forward_propagation(images)

        train_loss, cost = Process.error(forward_propgation_results, labels)

        image_summary_t = tf.image_summary(images.name, images, max_images = 2)

        summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()

        init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

        saver = tf.train.Saver()

        sess.run(init)

        saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())

        tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess = sess)

        train_dir = "/Users/Zanhuang/Desktop/NNP/model.ckpt"

        summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(train_dir, sess.graph)

        for step in range(100):
            start_time = time.time()
            print(sess.run([train_loss, cost]))
            duration = time.time() - start_time
            if step % 1 == 0:
                num_examples_per_step = FLAGS.batch_size
                examples_per_sec = num_examples_per_step / duration
                sec_per_batch = float(duration)

                format_str = ('%s: step %d, (%.1f examples/sec; %.3f ''sec/batch)')
                print (format_str % (datetime.now(), step, examples_per_sec, sec_per_batch))

                summary_str = sess.run(summary_op)
                summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)

                if step % 2 == 0:
                    checkpoint_path = train_dir
                    saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step = step)


def main(argv = None):
    train()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

Comment: Could you fix indentation? Right now, hard to say where the problem is?

Comment: Thanks, do you need the queue runner at all? It does not seem useful in this evaluation script, and origin of the error. If you do need it, is it the same way to read data than in the training script? It seems to choke on the data file.

Comment: Yes. I do need the runners. The script is not running without it. It is also the same way I read data on the training script.

Comment: Just to be sure, how about TF version (same for both)? Variable initialize toon seems early too. I am checking some code, but initialize ruin may have to cover saver and runner too.

Comment: It is the highest version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120890/discussion-between-eric-platon-and-zan-huang).